# How select multiple colors in october cms

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm developing a shopping cart system using October cms platform. Some product items will have multiple colours.

But using default colorpicker, I don't know how to select multiple colors. I searched all over the internet but I didn't get an answer for my situation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm may be just use repeater and add colour picker inside it so you can add `N no. of colour`  **[this is easy way but if you are using this attribute/values in search then this is not preferred way use `mm relation` for it then]**

***it will be stored as `json` in database field you can add this to model***

```
namespace  HardikSatasiya\Plugin\Models;
use Model;
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $jsonable = ['product_colors']; 

    ....
```

**schema**

```
    Schema::create('hardiksatasiya_pluginname_products', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('slug')->index();
        $table->text('product_colors')
```

You can define repeater like this.

```
product_colors:
    type: repeater
    form:
        fields:
            color:
                label: Background
                type: colorpicker
```

> As $model->product_colors will be having array of `colors` like his

```
$model->product_colors <=> [ 0 => [ 'color' => 'red'], 1 => [ 'color' => 'blue'] ]
```

> to access values you can directly use $model->product_colors it will be `array so you can loop through it`.

```
// $model->product_colors[0]->color -> red
// $model->product_colors[1]->color -> blue
```

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: great to see it helped you :)